# How to enumerate a Hashtable with foreach in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable

I'm trying to enumerate a `Hashtable` which is defined as:

```
private Hashtable keyPairs = new Hashtable();

foreach (SectionPair s in keyPairs)
{
    if (s.Section == incomingSectionNameVariable)
    {
        bExists = true;
        break;
    }
}
// more stuff here
```

But I get an error from Visual Studio 2013, "InvalidCastException was unhandled". Using a Dictionary, notwithstanding, I'm interested in knowing why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Are you sure all the elements in `keyPairs` can be casted to `SectionPair`? Also, you should not use non-generic `Hashtable`. Move to generic `HashSet<T>` to get compile-time type safety.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you can read in the [*Remarks*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) section of the [`Hashtable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable) class, the objects you enumerate are [`DictionaryEntry`s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry(v=vs.110).aspx). So you will have to rewrite it to something like:

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry s in keyPairs) {
   //Is Section the Key?
   if(s.Key == incomingSectionNameVariable) {
      bExists = true;
      break;
    }
}
```

A `DictionaryEntry` has a `Key` and `Value` element (that are of course the keys and the values in the `Hashtable`. Both are `Object`s since a `Hashtable` is not generic and thus the compiler can not know what the type of the `Key` and/or `Value` is.

I advice you however to use a [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) since here you can specify the type of the `Key` and `Value`. In that case an example could look like:

```
private Dictionary<string,int> keyPairs = new Dictionary<string,int>();

foreach( KeyValuePair<string,int> kvp in keyPairs) {
    //do something with kvp
}
```

But here `kvp.Key` will be a `string` so you don't have to cast it and it is safer to use.

Comment: That's just what I needed to understand. May the wind always be at your back. -su